# Bootstrap classes documentation(e.g. container-fluid/navbar-header/)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn bootstrap framework and find the docs for various examples attached to the official Bootstrap site (if I am right the official site is http://getbootstrap.com/ ).
I have spent hours trying to find an explanation for what the fluid container class is, and what it does. I can’t find any docs on the ‘navbar-header’ class either.

1)  I have browsed Bootstrap docs to find something about
    ‘container-fluid’. I can only find the following in the section
    ‘Scaffolding’. There is a description like this: “Create a fluid,
    two-column page with —great for
    applications and docs”. How on earth can I guess from that
    description what this container is for (that it is acting like a
    rubber container – it is expandable - if I understand well)

1. I have tried to find some docs on ‘navbar-header’ class. I have
   browsed through ‘Scaffolding’’/’Base CSS’/’Components’/’Java Script’
   sections and found nothing.

I am not trying to whinge, I just need someone to probably point me to the right docs or just a few tips how to interpret the explanation.
Could someone from the Guru Team throw some light on this, please? It will help all other developers struggling with similar problems.
Regards,
Janusz

Answer (score 0):

1. `.container-fluid` use fluid design ([read this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/)), that means, among other things, that make the grid responsive, and asign the `width` of columns `.col-md-*` in percentage instead of px
2. `.navbar-header` doesn't require much explanation, it's just part of the structure of [bootstrap navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default). Now if you still want to know exactly what is it for, you should look at the [bootstrap source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less#L31)